# Hibernate exception when create table

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, intellij-idea

I just started creating project in Hibernate, and I have problem at the begining.

While I try create a simple table I get these errors:

```
Dec 05, 2014 1:50:09 PM org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence logDeprecation
WARN: HHH015016: Encountered a deprecated javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider [org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence]; use [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] instead.
Dec 05, 2014 1:50:09 PM org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence logDeprecation
WARN: HHH015016: Encountered a deprecated javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider [org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence]; use [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] instead.
Dec 05, 2014 1:50:09 PM org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence logDeprecation
WARN: HHH015016: Encountered a deprecated javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider [org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence]; use [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] instead.
Dec 05, 2014 1:50:09 PM org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper logPersistenceUnitInformation
INFO: HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: NewPersistenceUnit
    ...]
Dec 05, 2014 1:50:09 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.7.Final}
Dec 05, 2014 1:50:09 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Dec 05, 2014 1:50:09 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Dec 05, 2014 1:50:10 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
Dec 05, 2014 1:50:10 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Dec 05, 2014 1:50:10 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000401: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gmlDatabase]
Dec 05, 2014 1:50:10 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=lukasz, password=****}
Dec 05, 2014 1:50:10 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false
Dec 05, 2014 1:50:10 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
Dec 05, 2014 1:50:10 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
Dec 05, 2014 1:50:10 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        User
        (name) 
    values
        (?)
Dec 05, 2014 1:50:11 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 1146, SQLState: 42S02
Dec 05, 2014 1:50:11 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: Table 'gmlDatabase.User' doesn't exist
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1763)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1683)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1187)
    at Main.main(Main.java:16)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:211)
    at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3032)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3558)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:98)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:490)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:179)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:324)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:288)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(JpaPersistEventListener.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:149)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:811)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:784)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:789)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1181)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'gmlDatabase.User' doesn't exist
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:360)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:978)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3887)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3823)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2435)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2582)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2530)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1907)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2141)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2077)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2062)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:208)
    ... 27 more
```

And i can't find solution. Strange is i get warning about deprecation of org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence, but i can't use it. I use org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider as is shown below.

Anything strange thing is error about no table named "User". Of course is not there, I want to create it!

Additionaly I am using Intellij Idea 14 if its important.
Tere are my class and config file:

```
persistence.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.1">

    <persistence-unit name="NewPersistenceUnit">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gmlDatabase"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="lukasz"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="p4ssw0rd"/>
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

User.java:

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

and Main.java:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("NewPersistenceUnit");
        EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

        User user = new User();

        user.setName("Janek");

        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        entityManager.persist(user);
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();


        entityManager.close();
         entityManagerFactory.close();
    }


}
```

Comment: Try avoiding reserved database specific keywords like 'USER' for table name.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe using `create-drop` will update an in-place schema to re-add the table that you dropped. Try:

```
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
```

This is create a schema if one doesn't exist, and attempt to modify an existing one to match the mapping you have defined.

Also see this,
[Hibernate hbm2ddl.auto possible values and what they do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438146/hibernate-hbm2ddl-auto-possible-values-and-what-they-do)

Comment: I try everything (update, create, create-drop) and nothing working.

Comment: Try adding @table annotations ex. @table(name="USER")

Comment: If i add it, i get : ERROR: Table 'gmlDatabase.USER' doesn't exist

Comment: Are you able to create Table manually? Check the User privileges.

Comment: Yes, I can create Table manually. And i have permissions to everything.

Answer (score 1):

First of all  check permissions of user (in this case yours is "lukasz"), be sure that you have  create database permission. If user doesn't have permission , you can use this command ;

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'lukasz'@'localhost';
```

Comment: Yes, i have all permissions.

Comment: Granting all permissions to my user, solved the issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Add a `@Table(schema="gmlDatabase")` to the Entity

**UPDATE**

I guess Hibernate creates an *AUTO_INCREMENT* for the primary key in the User table? If so you've to set the `GenerationType` to `IDENTITY`.

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```

Comment: I added something like this: `@Entity
@Table(schema="gmlDatabase"). `@table after `@entity. Is good? If yes, now i get error :"cannot resolve schema". But i assigned data sources and dont know why not working.

Answer (score 0):

A Couple things stand out to me.

It looks like the exception is coming from an attempt to insert into the user table. From the stack trace it looks like it's being thrown when you call persist. You also say you're trying to create the user table. Unless I've been misusing EM.persist() all these years, it won't create a table, it will just insert/update that record in the table. You need to actually go into your SQL and create the user table. Something like

```
CREATE TABLE gmlDatabase.User (
id NUMBER,
name VARCHAR(255)
);
```

Specific syntax may vary depending on what database software you are using

If the table isn't going to have the same name as the hibernate class name you'll need to add a name field to the @Table annotation.

```
@Table(name="user_table", schema="gmlDatabase")
public class Table {
...
```

I don't think you'll actually need that in this case, though. It looks like you want the class and table to both have the name "User".

Finally, try listing the specific class under the persistent-unit tag in your persistence.xml Something like

```
<persistence-unit name="NewPersistenceUnit">
    ...
    <class>com.pkg.otherpkg.User</class>
</persistence-unit>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I partly solved problem.
Partly, because I have to manually create table and correct columns. 
This is log, but it isn't so hopefully.
http://pastebin.com/uLhz5nUK

I rolling back every changes in my code, and now it look like in first post.

Now question is why hibernate doesn't create this table?